# How to bind custom fluent validation message to ModelState.Values.Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I want to return my custom message when take invalid values my model.Therefore I use the  Fluentvalidation.Create validators and asyncActionfilter. But Method returned default fluent message instead of  my custom message. Why?

My AsyncActionFilter Class

```
public class ModelValidatorFilterAttribute : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errorMessages =
                context.ModelState.Values
                    .Select(
                        x =>
                            new ExceptionResponse.ExceptionMessage { Message = x.Errors.First().ErrorMessage })
                    .ToList();

            throw new ValidationException(errorMessages);
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

My Validator

```
 public class MyValidator : AbstractValidator<MyRequestDto>
{
    public MyValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(s => s.ProductId).NotEmpty().NotNull()
                                 .WithMessage(x => "my custom message");
    }
}
```

My Startup config

```
services.AddFluentValidation();
        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        });
```

Response

```
{
"exceptionMessages": [
    {
        "message": "'Product Id' must not be empty.",
        "duration": 0,
        "type": "Type"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: hi. probably because you provided message only for the last rule not to all

Comment: How to provided all case with onu method? Is this possible? @ValentinMaschenko

Comment: If I am not wrong there is method that will check both if property is not null or empty. Give me a sec I will try to find

Comment: You know not empty will fail if value is null or empty. You can hover over that method and read definition. I.e. you just have to use only this method and provide message